# WPF tab keeping context only on first tab

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am building an application that I thought was working well until I realized a strange behavior in the tab controls. The short version is that selections made in one tab are causing subscribed events to trigger in another.

I have a main window which has three user controls:

1. a menu, which directs the content of the selection panel
2. a selection panel which creates tabs in the work area
3. a work area - a tab control.

In the case of one workflow a user is working with a list of items in the left panel, selects a specific item to work with and the details of that item are displayed in a tab in the work area.

Each Tab is made up of several subviewmodels of its own, representing grids composed from the Product data model - a Product has several Materials (SKUs). Each SKU has a BillOfMaterials, etc.

I have figured out where but not why the problem is occurring.

When the user presses a button on the Panel to view the item details it triggers a mediated event. The Work Area has a subscription to this event, which calls a method to create a new tab. I believe this is the correct pattern.

ItemTabVM has a host of other VM within it. Here is the code in the Work area VM:

```
...
        public _WorkAreaVM()
        {
            Mediator.Subscribe("newtab_item", LoadNewItemTab);
        }
        private void LoadNewItemTab(object obj)
        {
            String id = AppData.SelectedPanelValue;

            if (IsTabUnique(id) == true)
                TabList.Add(ItemTabVM(id));

            SetSelectedTab(id);
        }
...
```

XAML for the WorkArea

```
...

    <UserControl x:Class="CWApp.Views._WorkAreaUC"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CWApp.Views"
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CWApp.ViewModels"
                 mc:Ignorable="d">
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <vm:_WorkAreaVM/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>
    
        <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="WorkArea" />
            <TabControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding TabList}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" >
    
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ItemTabVM}">
                        <local:ItemUC/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VendorTabVM}">
                        <local:VendorTabUC/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.Resources>
    
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ITabViewModel}">
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding CloseCommand}">X</Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </UserControl>

...
```

XAML for each ItemTabUC

```
...
    
    <UserControl x:Class="CWApp.Views.ItemTabUC "
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CWApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:CWApp.Helpers"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CWApp.Views"
             
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductMainVM}">
                    <local:ProductMainUC/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MaterialGridVM}">
                    <local:MaterialGridUC/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BOMGridVM}">
                    <local:BOMGridUC/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RouterGridVM}">
                    <local:RouterGridUC/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VendorGridVM}">
                    <local:VendorGridUC/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding ProductMain}" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding MaterialGrid}" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding BOMGrid}" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding RouterGrid}" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding VendorGrid}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
    
...
```

One of the VM in ItemTabVM is the MaterialVM (DataTable of SKUs). When the user selects a SKU it should change the BillOfMaterialVM (DataTable of Components) based on the selected SKU.

MaterialUC DataGrid SelectedItem binds to VM
...

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dgMaterials" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding MaterialTable}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

...

When MaterialVM changes, it tells ItemTabVM there was a change. This is handled through the datagrid SelectedItem control, which, in turn, triggers a mediated event.

...

```
    public Material SelectedMaterial
    {
        get { return _selectedMaterial; }
        set
        {
            _selectedMaterial = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMaterial");
            NotifyMaterialChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyMaterialChanged()
    {
        Mediator.Notify("materialChange", true);
    }
```

...

ItemTabVM (ancestor of MaterialVM and BillOfMaterialVM) is subscribed to changes to the MaterialVM.SelectedMaterial, and when found, tells the BOMVM what datapoint to load.

...

```
    private void CreateSubscriptions()
    {
       Mediator.Subscribe("materialChange", SetMaterialChanged);
    }
    private void SetMaterialChanged(object obj)
    {
        String n = ThisProduct.ProductID; //error discovery
        if(MaterialGrid.SelectedMaterial != null)
            BOMGrid.SetGrid(MaterialGrid.SelectedMaterial);
    }
```

...

The line marked "error discovery" uses the ProductID loaded in the ItemTabVM to reveal which itemtab is actually being activated. No matter from which MaterialVM the trigger was sent, it was always Tab1 ItemTabVM subscription that fired.

Why arent the Tab subscriptions staying local to the context of their children?

Comment: TabControls can be a bit confusing sometimes, since there only one content area, no matter how many tabs are opened... Can you share the xaml snippet for a tabcontrol that contains your problem?

Comment: @grek40 thank you. Since I have better defined the problem I have added more description and code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your application logic is really hard to follow by your explanations. I mean you tried well, but for me who doesn't know what's going on it's a hard nut to crack. Maybe you could show the view model logic/interaction you are talking about.

First you have to understand that the `TabControl` is a hybrid control, being an `ItemsControl` and a `ContentControl`. The `ItemsControl` part handles the `TabItems` that are displayed inside a `TabPanel`. These items are the tab headers. The `ContentControl` part handles the actual content of the selected `TabItem`. This means all tab headers share the same `ContentPresenter`.

When switching between the tabs i.e. selecting the next `TabItem` the content is replaced. The point is that when the previous content is replaced, it loses its state. It's the responsibility of the developer to persist the data before switching a tab. This often leads to unexpected effects as most people assume each tab has its own associated content.

To overcome this you should structure your work area as followed:

Create a master view model which is the `DataContext` of the `TabControl`. This view model exposes the data source for the `TabControl` but also provides the logic to control the tab handling. The individual tab view models should not care about other tabs. It's the master view model that should observe each data item and handle events e.g., by initializing related data items or showing/selecting the next tab by selecting the appropriate data item.

From your descriptions it appears that your view model is listening to view events to know when to change tabs. This is wrong.
Your view model or in this case the master view model should expose a `ICommand`. This `ICommand`, when executed by a `Button` in the view, will set a e.g., `ViewModel.SelectedTab` property which binds to the `TabControl.SelectedItem` property.
When you change the selected `TabItem` by setting the `SelectedItem` property, you can subscribe to the items events.

The master view model n this scenario is the only view model that knows about other view models (tab items). This structure should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I still have to digest your comments a bit, but I did add additional detail and code which might make following the process easier.

Comment: ok, I think what you're saying is that the _WorkArea ViewModel should be the Master DataContext and my events should really live here, rather than in the ItemTabVM?

Comment: You said you are exchanging data between the tabs using events. I said a master view model like the work area view model which exposes the item models should handle the exchange - manage its items or collections. Generally this model knows when items are added or  removed and can subscribe/unsubscribe to item events accordingly. If one item changes, the master view model can iterate over the items collection to update all other items. It just simpler and cleaner. I still don't understand your code as you only post very short snippets. Changing your structure will very likely fix your problem.

Comment: Otherwise check if every `ItemTabVM` really subscribes to the event or only the first is subscribing. You only showed how subscription is implemented but not how the instances are subscribing. Better post complete classes where you may remove unimportant code. An isolated method doesn't help when the problem has more context. We don't want to review e.g. `CreateSubscriptions()` but need to understand how it is used. That's why I gave you this general answer (of which I believe will fix your problem).